# pyplot tab character

Tags: python, tabs, matplotlib

I am trying to use the tab character in pyplot. However, the tab character is displaying a square, not the tab space I require.

My code is:

```
fig = pl.figure()
fig.text(.1,.05, "test \t test", bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was surprised that `pylab.show` actually shows some spaces in place of your square. But `savefig` does not try to be smart and gives what you describe. Now, how many spaces does one tab take ? This question makes no sense. Is it 4 for you ? I will pick 4.2 for me. This means you need to decide how many spaces you want a tab to take in your text, i.e.:

```
fig = pylab.figure()
text = "test \t test".replace("\t", "    ")
fig.text(.1,.05, text, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
```

Or, maybe you want to simply expand your tabs using "standard" conventions:

```
text = "test \t test".expandtabs()
```

Comment: This is a solution which I tried, but doesn't help with tab alignment. I am using the tabs to display columns of data 'cleanly', which was the main benefit to using them.

Comment: I would suggest that you post a question about how to "display columns of data cleanly", then, or that you check Matplotlib's gallery (http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and look for what you need. (The solution does not involve tabulations.)