# weird characters appear when plotting in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
median = 2.38
dates=['2013-01-14', '2013-01-26', '2013-01-26', '2013-02-16', '2013-05-08', '2013-08-03', '2013-09-26', '2013-10-28', '2013-12-01', '2014-01-03', '2014-02-08', '2014-04-26', '2014-05-06', '2014-05-30', '2014-05-30', '2014-07-30', '2015-03-24', '2016-09-10', '2017-03-03', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23', '2020-02-23']
prices=[2.39, 2.39, 4.31, 2.39, 2.2, 2.31, 2.24, 2.38, 2.38, 2.38, 2.38, 2.14, 8.1, 2.14, 2.14, 4.31, 4.54, 4.58, 4.58, 2.5, nan, nan, 1.86, nan, 2.0, 1.75, 4.92, 6.43, 1.86, 4.5]
desc=['F32T8/SPX41/ECO2', 'F32T8/TL841/ALTO', 'FO32/841/ECO', 'F32T8/841/XP/ECO']
plt.plot(dates, prices, label=f'Median: {median}')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
newline = "\n"
tab="\t\t"
x=f'Traditional\tProducts:{(newline+tab+" "*9).join(desc)}{newline}Median:  {median}'
plt.title(x,fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=40)
plt.show()
```

when I print x it is exactly what I want as the title of figure, I am getting weird symbols and not the way I formatted the text
[image: expected output]

Edit1: Current Output
[image: Plot Image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the actual output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: @G.Anderson The title of plot contains weird symbols and is not the way `x` should be

Comment: What "weird symbols"? You seem to have included your desired output, but not shown how your actual output is wrong

Comment: @G.Anderson I added the current plot figure,Check Title

Comment: pyplot doesn't display tab characters. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964872/pyplot-tab-character) shows some workarounds

Comment: @G.Anderson you mean I should replace the \t with spaces to solve?

Comment: That seems to be the solution, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208449/discussion-between-madboy-and-g-anderson).